# ICP registration issue

Tags: python-3.x, point-cloud-library

I use open3d ICP algorithm to register two sets point clouds.
The input were similar two point clouds sets. However the result showed the error value is high and if I use the viewer, it showed the 2 sets were only partially matched. 
Could someone tell me how to improve it? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could provide us some screenshots so we know in more details.
From my experience,

**1. bounding box center:** Is your point cloud in the center? As far as I know the first is to make the PCs in the center for further ICP registration.

**2. Scale:** Did you scale your two PCs to same level?

**3. Iteration :** Some cases needs more iterations to find the match but the trade off is longer processing time. So maybe try to increase the iterations and see how it works.